# HtmlUnit not finding form and not handling postback

Tags: forms, postback, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit (2.35) in Java on this url https://www.pharmacy.ohio.gov/Licensing/RosterRequests.aspx to select options from the radio buttons and then click the download button and receive the file.

I'm fairly certain I am setting the radio buttons correctly but I'm not sure if I am pressing the button or, if I am, how to detect the start of the download which is accomplished by a postback (I think).

I've tried waiting for Javascript, turning off Javascript, looping for 60 seconds while checking the contentType and creating a listener.

I also thought to load the form from the page as perhaps the HtmlUnit click() action was just firing off the Javascript and not doing the post action but HtmlUnit can't seem to find a form on the page even though there is one there.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebClient webClient;
        webClient = new WebClient( BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60 );                    

        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); 
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2","TLSv1.1","TLSv1"});  
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        HtmlPage MainPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.pharmacy.ohio.gov/Licensing/RosterRequests.aspx");
        HtmlElement body = MainPage.getBody();
        if (dbg) System.out.println("MainPage = " + MainPage); 

\\ All of the below are empty:

        System.out.println( "MainPageForm = " + MainPage.getFirstByXPath( "//*[@id=\"form1\"]"));
        System.out.println( "Form List = " + MainPage.getElementsByIdAndOrName( "form#form1"));
        System.out.println( "Form List = " + MainPage.getForms());
        System.out.println( "Form? = " + MainPage.querySelector("#form1"));
        System.out.println( "Form? = " + MainPage.getFirstByXPath( "//form[@action=\"RosterRequests.aspx\"]" ));
        System.out.println( "Form? = " + MainPage.getElementById( "#form1"));
        System.out.println( "MainPageButton = " + MainPage.getFirstByXPath( "//*[@id=\"phBody_rblLicenseType_5\"]") );

\\ Code to click buttons: 

HtmlRadioButtonInput rad_status = (HtmlRadioButtonInput)MainPage.getHtmlElementById("phBody_rblLicenseStatus_1");
rad_status.setChecked( true );
HtmlRadioButtonInput rad_tddd = MainPage.getHtmlElementById( "phBody_rblLicenseType_1");
rad_tddd.setChecked( true );
HtmlInput btn_download = (HtmlInput)MainPage.getHtmlElementById( "phBody_btnSubmit" );   
WebResponse response = btn_download.click().getWebResponse();

\\ ContentType never changes 

        int tries = 30;

        while ( tries > 0 ) {
            //System.out.println( response.getWebRequest().toString());
            System.out.println( response.getContentType());
            synchronized (response) { response.wait(1000);}

        tries--;
        }

        webClient.close();


    }
```

Nothing is ever downloaded and the ContentType never changes. In a browser, the dev tools show the aspx page is reloaded with a different ContentType which triggers the download dialog.

Comment: Did some analysis on this. Looks like the root cause of the problem is somewhere in HtmlUnit. Please open an issue (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues)

Comment: Thanks! I'll do just that. Appreciate the analysis!

Answer (score 0):

This works with HtmlUnit 2.36.0 (or at least with the latest 2.35.0-SNAPSHOT.

```
final String url = "https://www.pharmacy.ohio.gov/Licensing/RosterRequests.aspx";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

    HtmlRadioButtonInput rad_status = (HtmlRadioButtonInput)page.getHtmlElementById("phBody_rblLicenseStatus_1");
    rad_status.setChecked( true );
    HtmlRadioButtonInput rad_tddd = page.getHtmlElementById( "phBody_rblLicenseType_1");
    rad_tddd.setChecked( true );

    HtmlInput btn_download = (HtmlInput)page.getHtmlElementById( "phBody_btnSubmit" );
    WebResponse response = btn_download.click().getWebResponse();

    try (InputStream in = response.getContentAsStream();
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/tmp/test.xlsx")) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```